# slide out menu move to another view controller

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I followed this great tutorial on a slide out menu using UIKit Dynamics, [Slide Out Menu](http://UIKit%20Dynamicshttp://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/animated-components-with-uikit-dynamics-part-1--cms-20942). The code has been slightly modified to reduce duplication of code.  I'm handling the touch event in the MenuComponent Class.  Now, I'm trying to move to another view controller when the item is selected.  The menu is created in code so I can't use segue's.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
[[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setSelected:NO];
[self toggleMenu];
self.isMenuShown = NO;
   if(indexPath.row == 0){
      //move to the testViewController
}
```

How do you remove the current view and present a new one?  My hierarchy is a navigation controller then my testViewController.

Edit:  I did find this code which I tried, but my problem is the when the menu is present and I try to present the view I get an error:

```
testViewController *test = (testViewController*)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"testViewController"];
[self presentViewController:test animated:YES completion:nil];

Warning: Attempt to present <testViewController: 0x7c095470> on <MenuComponent: 0x7ae4ce50> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out by creating a delegate for the MenuComponent and then pass the view like so:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
   UIViewController * test = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"test"] ;
   [delegate didCallViewController:test];
```